# Setup dnsmasq to resolve host name to local machine's IP

Tags: networking, dns, dnsmasq

I'm running `dnsmasq` as a simple DNS for resolving `myserver.local.example.com` to the local IP address of the server where `dnsmasq` is running on. Everything else is forwarded to public DNS.

Assuming the server's IP address is 192.168.1.12 then my command looks like this:

```sh
dnsmasq --no-hosts --no-resolv --localise-queries \
  --server=1.1.1.1 --server=8.8.8.8 --server=8.8.4.4 \
  --host-record=myserver,myserver.local.example.com,192.168.1.12
```

In case multiple network interfaces are attached I set multiple `--host-record` entries, one for each IP address:

```sh
dnsmasq --no-hosts --no-resolv --localise-queries \
  --server=1.1.1.1 --server=8.8.8.8 --server=8.8.4.4 \
  --host-record=myserver,myserver.local.example.com,192.168.1.12 \
  --host-record=myserver,myserver.local.example.com,192.168.99.57
```

*This works as expected*. The hostname is resolved to the IP address I configure. However, I have two questions on how to improve this:

1. Is there a way of configuring this without *knowing* the IP address of the server? I'm using a bash script that parses the IP address from `ifconfig` output and passes it to `dnsmasq` but this seems cumbersome.
2. If the IP address of the server changes for whatever reason, e.g. the network gets connected *after* `dnsmasq` is already started, I have to manually restart `dnsmasq`. In context of the previous question, it would be preferable if `dnsmasq` could automatically detect that and update without manual restart.

Any thoughts or suggestions? Or maybe there's even an alternative to `dnsmasq` that's more suitable for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
--interface-name=<name>,<interface>
```

e.g

```
--interface-name=myserver.local.example.com,enp2s0
```

See http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html fore more details

With the default configuration, Dnsmasq is able to see interface link and ip address events, and should not need to be restarted to publish "interface" DNS names when interfaces go down and up.